# How to render ReactJS component from outside of JS class it's defined in and/or with dynamic id element name?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, reactjs

If I defined a ReactJS class in say dialog.js:

```
var divStyle = {
  padding: '15px',
  paddingBottom: '12px'
};

var Dialog = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>...</div>
    );
  }
});
```

In the above I define a class.. but in every example I see there is also the `React.renderComponent(<Dialog/>,document.getElementById('someId'));`

The problem I have with this is.. if I want to use this component on different pages with different IDs to render it at, or perhaps for several different IDs, I can't hard-code the id in the actual class it's at. I supposed I can pass in the ID in some manner??

But furthermore, I also want to be able to render the component in say a different JS class, one loaded AFTER the loading of this js class. I have an app.js class for my SPA app, that is loaded last. In it, when a user clicks a link, I may want to only render this component at that time. I do realize in the render method I can control in some way whether or not it's actually rendered.. but my thinking is also to not even bothering inserting it into the DOM unless an action occurs. Sort of like lazy insertion I guess?

I've tried in my app.js:

```
function () {
  React.renderComponent(<Dialog/>,...);
}
```

but obviously this doesn't work as this JS is not a JSX JS file. So I tried using React.renderComponent(Dialog,...); thinking the Dialog class is globally defined, so it would be available, but that too fails.

So how do I use the Dialog class in another function to render it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting something conceptually wrong here:

> but in every example I see there is also the `React.renderComponent(<Dialog/>,document.getElementById('someId'));`

The fact that the short examples are followed by a `renderComponent` call is for the trivial reason to show the demos. Once again, keep in mind that in React, `<Dialog />` desugars to `Dialog()`. If you don't call it nothing happens.

So, simply don't call  until you need it.

Also, I don't understand what you mean by:

> but obviously this doesn't work as this JS is not a JSX JS file

Since you can just process that file through JSX?

If you're having trouble mentally mapping JSX to functions and vice-versa: try the live compiler here: http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html

Comment: You know what, another post on another blog basically cleared this up saying the same thing you did. The problem I had with what you just said is I tried that and my component didn't show up still. I am guessing I must now have some code bit wrong. But yes, I did not realize that <Dialog/> becomes Dialog. Actually.. I thought it did, then I tried: var dialog = new Dialog(); React.renderComponent(dialog,...); and when that didn't work I was more confused. But now that I understand it is how it's done, I just need to look at my code and figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: Alright! Don't do var dialog = new Dialog(); React.renderComponent(dialog,...); It's a bad idea as you're taking a reference and mounting it on several places. This encourages unexpected mutations. Whenever you need, call Dialog() each time. <Dialog /> doesn't become Dialog. It becomes Dialog().

Comment: Ah.. ok.. thank you. I am also looking at Vue.js so trying to decide between the two now, thinking both may work well together.

Comment: Alright chenglou.. I got around to playing with this again finally.. and it's sadly still not working. As I said, I defined Dialog in dialog.js. I load that before my app.js. In app.js (which uses jquery for now) in the $( document ).ready(function() {  I have React.renderComponent(Dialog(), document.getElementById('react_dialog'));

When I reload my page, it says ReferenceError: Dialog not defined. I then also see a invalid Object Initializer further down in the JS console window. Am I doing it right? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: There are lots of things that can go wrong here, and it probably doesn't concern React. Have you tried to see if anything you expose from dialog.js is available in app.'s? (Btw, it'll be faster if you join the #reactjs irc channel)

Comment: I think my JS skills are lacking lol. I did make sure an alert box works in the JS file the class is in, and that the JS file is being loaded. I thought I understood that if you load JS1 (where class is defined) before JS2, that JS1 var f = func() would be "global" and available in JS2. Anyway, what is the IRC server? Last time I did IRC there was EFNET, FREENODE, etc. I can't seem to find the IRC info other than the room is #reactjs.

Comment: `React.renderComponent((
   <App />
), document.body);` so without this component won't render if even it's tag persists in DOM? Any workaround to trigger component automatically?